# Normalisation to 3NF, does the foreign key have to be dependent on the primary key?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

If every attribute has to be dependent on the primary key, does this include the foreign key?

Does the foreign key always go in the 'many' table (in a one to many relationship)?

Answer (score 1):

3NF requires that every non-key attribute of a relation is non-transitively dependent on every candidate key. So if the foreign key you are referring to consists of a non-key attribute or attributes then the answer to your first question is yes.

A foreign key is a set of attributes subject to a referential integrity constraint. Typically that means the "many" side of a one-to-many relationship between two tables, although it's quite possible to have foreign keys in a one-to-one relationship as well.